# How to check if substring is contained within word Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex pattern that looks at a string to see if there is a "." followed by letters or numbers or both with no space in between.

Currently I have:
`Pattern.matches(".*(\\W+|\\d+|[a-z]+)\\.[a-z]+", testStr)`
But this doesn't work if there are numbers or symbols after the "." Can someone help me find a regex string that will return true for the string:
`asdad-asdd/asdcs.pd(210)fsd`

Just to reiterate the criteria for a successful match is the string contains any possible combination of letters, numbers, and/or symbols before and after a "."

Comment: Maybe replace `\\.[a-z]+` with `\\.\\S+`? To match any non-whitespace chars.

Comment: `[0-9a-z]` matches letters and numbers. If you want to add upper case letters use `[0-9a-zA-Z]`

Comment: try using one of those regex pattern tester sites that breaks down your regex pattern and explains each chunk to help debugging

Comment: I m not too sure, but isnt this kind of redundant? `(\\W+|\\d+|[a-z]+)` you already have `.*` that matches any character for 0 or more times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match these strings by replacing `[a-z]+` with `[a-z\d\p{Punct}]+`:

```java
Pattern.matches(".*(\\W+|\\d+|[a-z]+)\\.[a-z\\d\\p{Punct}]+", testStr)
```

The `[a-z\d\p{Punct}]+` pattern matches lowercase ASCII letters, digits or punctuation. Add `A-Z` into the brackets if you plan to allow uppercase ASCII letters. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cYDHoo/1).

However, you might also match any non-whitespace chars with `\S+`:

```java
Pattern.matches(".*(\\W+|\\d+|[a-z]+)\\.\\S+", testStr)
```

If you do not want to allow another dot:

```java
Pattern.matches(".*(\\W+|\\d+|[a-z]+)\\.[^\\s.]+", testStr)
```

Here, `[^\\s.]+` matches one or more chars other than whitespace and `.` chars.